# TableRow taking more space than usual android TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Good day, i am having troubles with the following image below. As you can see, the table rows are taking so much space and i would like to reduce them because there are other view widgets under them. how can i achieve this?  Thank you.

[image]

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_date_filter">

  <TableRow
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1">

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="@string/from_text">
</TextView>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="01-01-2012">
</TextView>
</TableRow>

  <View
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1px"
      android:background="#606060">
  </View>

<TableRow>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="@string/to_text">
</TextView>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="01-09-2012">
</TextView>
</TableRow>

      <View
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1px"
      android:background="#606060">
  </View>

    <TableRow>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="@string/groupby">
</TextView>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="day">
</TextView>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_filter_button_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reset_filters">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the layout weight from the `TableRows`.

Comment: @Luksprog sorry for the late response. i have done that but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your layout and in the end it appears the `weightSum` and `layout_weight` are not responsible. Setting the `TableLayout` to wrap the content and the `layout_weight` on the `TextViews` seems to expand the `TableLayout` and make it have the behavior you see.

If you set the width of the `TableLayout` to `FILL_PARENT` the problems should go away:

```
// ...
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
// ...
```

This somehow makes sense as you try to use the layout weight when the parent doesn't really have space to spare(because of the `wrap_content`), nothing good can come from this.

Also, if that is all your layout, you could improve it and add the `Button` directly to the `TableLayout`(in another `TableRow`) removing the need for the wrapper `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for it. your solution works. i also found out that i could reduce it by setting the maxHeight attribute for the TextViews but your solution is cleaner i think. Also I want to have a rounded TableLayout, so the button cannot be inside the TableLayout.

Comment: can i use this opportunity to ask how to make a rounded TableLayout?.. i know you can define a drawable with shape rectangle and a color and use it as a background. but i don't want the background to have any color, i just want the lines\border of the rectangle to be visible. any idea how to do that?

Comment: @sparrow I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to keep the current drawable that you use as background for the `TableLayout` and also have rounded borders around the `TableLayout`?

Comment: yes i want to have rounded borders around the table layout, but i don't want inside the borders to have a color. from the image below, i have it set to white thats why it looks thats way. if i set it to blue, all the views in the table layout will appear on a blue background. what i want is for the border lines to be blue but inside it will be white, so in summary, the views will be on a white background (or set by the LinearLayout) but the the border lines around it will be blue.  hope am clear.

Comment: @sparrow Is this( https://gist.github.com/3749142 ) what you're looking for?(set as the background for the `TableLayout`)

Answer (score 0):

The layout_weight is used to tell the layout to forcefully fill the space. In above layout the TableRow weight is specified as 1 and weighSum as 3. Remove the layout_weight and weightSum it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="From" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="01-01-2012" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#606060" >
            </View>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="To" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="01-09-2012" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#606060" >
            </View>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_from_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Group By" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datefilter_text_to_id"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="day" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_filter_button_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the output layout :

[image]

The problems i noted and hence corrected are:

- Added the the `row separation` as a separate row, instead of ambiguous view inside `TableLayout`
- Changed the `layout_width` of `TableLayout` from `wrap_content` to `fill_parent`